# Add two numbers which are stored as in reversed linked list form

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. Digits are stored in reverse order and each of nodes contain a single digit. The task is adding two numbers and return it as a linked list.

- Input: `(2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)`
- Output: `7 -> 0 -> 8`
- Explanation: `342 + 465 = 807`

There are several solutions for this problem. I'm trying to solve it by converting linked-list formed digits into numbers. I already did convert the lists to numbers but my problem starts here. You are given a linked-list definition and you can not break it. You don't have a default(empty) constructor in this definition. I am not able to reverse my integer sum into linked-list form yet. Here is my code:

```
public class ListNode {    //given linked -list definition. Should not be manipulated.
     int val;
      ListNode next;
     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
       int num1 = getNumber(l1);
        int num2 = getNumber(l2);
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        return ??  //some how I should return a LinkedList where my sum is converted into it
    }



//getNumber converts given linked-lists into integers 
    public int getNumber(ListNode head) {
       ListNode tmp = head;
    int number = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    while(tmp != null) {
        number += tmp.val * Math.pow(10, pass) ;
        tmp = tmp.next;
        pass++;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Are you suppose to put the 7->0->8 in to a new LinkedList? Are you allowed to create a new LinkedList? you are returning a ListNode variable which could contain only one value

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a whole new list.

Start by creating a new head node. What should it contain? The last digit of the `sum`, right? So get the last digit of `sum`: `int lastDigit = sum %10` and put it into a new link: `new ListNode(lastDigit)`.

Then do it for the next digit, and the next one, until `sum == 0`. Remember to link `ListNode` to each other after creating each one. It would probably be something like `prevNode.next = new ListNode(lastDigit)`

Answer (score 2):

The very purpose of this exercise is to use the given data structure to perform the computation. You are not supposed to convert the linked list to an `int`. Why, the values might not fit within the limits of an `int`. Using a linked list you could perform the operation on numbers with thousands of digits.

Here's an incomplete sketch that should help you, without spoiling the exercise.

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    return addTwoNumbers(l1, l2, 0);
}

private ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, int carry) {
    // TODO: know when to stop!
    // ex: if you have reached the end of l1, then apply carry to l2, if needed, and return
    // ex: if you have reached the end of l2, then apply carry to l1, if needed, and return

    int val = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
    ListNode node = new ListNode(val % 10);
    node.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next, val / 10);
    return node;
}

private ListNode addOne(ListNode l1) {
    // TODO
}
```